# Cython exetension class __getattr__ not doing the same behavoir with python's class counter part

Tags: python, initialization, cython

Edit: the problem is more complicated than the first question I asked, so I deleted everything and re-edit the question.

I tried to make a class in python, the following code works:
From my test_loop.pyd file

```
class mockClass:
    def __init__(self,val):
        self._val = val
    def __getattr__(self,attrName):
        print('Getattr:',attrName)
        print('This work on python:',self.__dict__)
        try:
            return self.__dict__[attrName]
        except:
            raise AttributeError("Unknow ",attrName)
    def __add__(self,val):
        return mockClass(self._val+val)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self._val)
def test_func():
    print('In test func')
    myList = [1,2,3]
    for ii,item in enumerate(myList):
        if (ii==0):
            out = mockClass(item)
        else:
            print('Add:',item)
            out += item

    return out
```

And the module works, my test.py file:

```
import test_loop
a = test_loop.test_func()
print(a)
```

But when I change the python class to cython class I got stuck in the recursive loop: the **getattr** (I tried **getattribute** too) get stuck because it try to find **dict**, which is, again, require function **getattr**.

```
cdef class mockClass:
    cdef int _val
    def __init__(self,val):
        self._val = val
    def __getattr__(self,attrName):
        print('Getattr:',attrName)
        print('This work on python:',self.__dict__)
        try:
            return self.__dict__[attrName]
        except:
            raise AttributeError("Unknow ",attrName)
    def __add__(self,val):
        return mockClass(self._val+val)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self._val)
```

I can't find any functional **getattr** example of cython extension class.

Comment: Why not just do `mySum = sum(myList)` and move on?

Comment: Your original code gets cythonized (obviously). `<int> mySum += item` isn't cython syntax, so it doesn't work. Please provide [mcve]

Comment: @ead: I know, what's I'm trying to say is I'm looking for a syntax that allow me to tell the compiler that please assume that the variable mySum is already initialized somewhere else and I know what I'm doing

Comment: @Booboo: because I provide the sum function as a simplified version of what I actually want. I actually wanted: 
```
mySum.mySpecialAppend(item) 
```

Comment: @mqnguyen1988, still the code you have provided gets cythonized. The code you have problems with must be different. Thus, please provide [mcve].

Comment: @ead: you are right! I'm working on a minimal reproducible example, while doing so I realized that the problem isn't come from what I'm think of. I just copied and paste the code on cython and it's not working anymore so I jumped too fast in the conclusion. I'm working on this, may be it's completely irrelevant to the title.

Comment: "I'm looking for a syntax that allow me to tell the compiler that please assume that the variable mySum is already initialized somewhere else and I know what I'm doing" - `global mySum`?

Comment: @ead: sorry I can't get the minimal reproductive code to function because I got another error on the way. I'll try to work on it. I posted my problem here anyway.

Comment: [cdef classes do not have a `__dict__` by default](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/extension_types.html#dynamic-attributes) - the documentation isn't explicitly clear on this but I've linked to the bit that shows how to add it.

Comment: @DavidW: thank you for your answer. So do you know how to make an implementation of __getattr__ that doesn't stuck in an infinite recursive? I seem can't find an example anywhere.

Comment: `__getattr__` is only called if the attribute hasn't been found by normal means. Therefore there's _never_ any point in looking in `__dict__` because if the attribute was in `__dict__` then `__getattr__` would not have been called.

Comment: So to clarify: your Python `__getattr__` is pointless (it always fails). Your Cython `__getattr__` is broken. In both cases the right thing to do is to delete them.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a the built-in sum function?

```py
mySym = sum(myList)
```

Comment: Because the sum function is just an reduced problem. I actually wanted to use a custom function : mySum.mySpecialAppend(item)

Comment: Then you should really think about updating your question and telling the *whole* story so there is a chance somebody can give you an answer that will satisfy you.

Comment: @Booboo: yes my problem is not that easy to explain, so while working on simplify the problem, I discover another problem. I did edit my post so you can follow what I have tested. Sorry I jumped too fast to the conclusion.